# Looking for a Java class in a set of JARs with find, unzip, grep

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, find, java

I was trying to find the JAR containing a Java Class. JARs are in zip format.

My first attempt was:

```
$ find -name "*3.0.6.RELEASE.jar" | xargs -l1 unzip -l \
    | grep stereotype.Controller
      554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
      554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
```

I found the class, but I still don't know which of the 25 matching files contains it (there are two JARs containing it). So I thought to use `tee` in the middle to output the file names.

```
$ find -name "*3.0.6.RELEASE.jar" | tee - | xargs -l1 unzip -l \
    | grep stereotype.Controller
  554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
  554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
  554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
  554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
```

I'd have expected to see a filename followed by the Controller.class for matching files and by the next filename for non mathing. However, now that I think about it, standard output just flows in the pipe and gets processed by xargs, so it makes sense.

I could use standard error, but then, I suppose, that since the processes are running concurrently, I could have timing issues that make the output not in the order I would hope to see.

So there must be a better way to approach this problem, anyone has ideas?

**UPDATE**: While waiting for an answer, I wrote a horrible Perl one liner that does the trick, but looking forward to see more elegant solutions.

```
$ find -name "*3.0.6.RELEASE.jar" | perl -e 'while (<>) { \
    $file=$_; @class=`unzip -l $_`; foreach (@class) { \
    if (/stereotype.Controller/) {print "$file $_";} } }'
```

Output:

```
./spring-context/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
   554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
./org.springframework.context/3.0.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
   554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
find -name "*3.0.6.RELEASE.jar" -exec sh -c 'unzip -l "{}" | grep -q stereotype.Controller' \; -print
```

There's no need for `xargs` or a `for` loop here. All can be done with a single `find`. If you want to also output the content that got grepped, just remove the `-q` option to `grep` - but notice that the `grep` matches  will appear *before* each file name. For a clearer output, you can add `-exec echo \;` at the very end.

Comment: +1, I always wanted to see how buffered items from find can be passed on to two items. Good stuff!!

Answer (score 2):

In your 1st one-liner, in the `grep` command add `-H` option. That is to include the file name in the result.

Here is from the man-page -

```
-H, --with-filename
              Print the filename for each match.</strike>
```

**UPDATE**

May be this script will help out -

```
#!/bin/bash

searchSTR="YOUR SEARCH"

for i in `find . -name "*jar"`
do
  echo "Scanning $i ..."
  jar tvf $i | grep $searchSTR > /dev/null
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    echo "==> Found \"$searchSTR\" in $i"
  fi
done
```

**One-Liner:**

```
for i in `find . -name "*.jar"`; do jar tvf $i | grep "search pattern" && echo $i ; done
```

The only sad part is the name of the jar file will be displayed after the `grep` content

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't help, since it's already processed with unzip, is too late to get the file name. Here is the output: `(standard input):      554  2011-08-18 16:49   org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.class`

Comment: I saw the update, it's conceptually similar to my Perl, I think I will probably change it to accept a parameter for the search string, look into my `.m2` Maven repo, and save the script (well formatted and commented instead of the one liner) in `/usr/local/bin/searchJar`. I will do it in the next few days, unless someone will tell me that there is a simpler solution.

Comment: That sounds right, you can make this into a one-liner but because we need to look inside the jar file, I don't really know a way of doing `grep` without `jar tvf`. The first echo can be removed. I just added it so that you can quickly browse through the jar files, our `find` command identifies.

Comment: Added a one-liner. Hope that helps!

Comment: @jaypalsingh if you really found the printing order sad, maybe a slight variation of your code could suffice to render you happy again: `SEARCH="Logger"; time while read jar _; do resultset=$(grep "${SEARCH}.*.class" < <(tar tf $jar)); if [ ${#resultset} -gt 0 ]; then printf "%s\n%s\n" "--> Found $SEARCH in $jar:" "$resultset"; fi; resultset=""; done < <(find . -type f -name "*.jar")`. It's even mighty fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

An old thread but this looks like a cleaner way to get this done:
http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~leif/opensource/cpcheck/CpCheckApp.html

```
Windows:
    cpcheck [flags] classpath [classpath]*
Unix:
    ./cpcheck.sh [flags] classpath [classpath]*
Java:
    java -jar cpcheck.jar [flags] classpath [classpath]*
```

Comment: where we should download cpcheck.jar file?